# Intellisense auto-complete-on-tab-only reverts every time Visual Studio is started

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, intellisense, visual-studio-2022

Every time I start Visual Studio I need to click:

> Edit > IntelliSense > **<s>stop automatically changing my code without
> even notifying me! (unless I press Tab)</s>** (paraphrased) Switch between automatic and tab-only IntelliSense completion

so that Visual Studio won't change my code. The setting doesn't persist from one Visual Studio launch to the next.

How can I make it stick?

(Using VS 2022 version 17.4)

Comment: That is more of a "command" than it is a setting and I think that may be why its not able to be saved through sessions.  There is a keyboard shortcut for it though: CTRL + ALT + Space.  That at least makes it faster to enable (there is an icon for it also on the toolbar unless your toolbar is customized to not have it display)

Comment: @TimothyG. Thanks. There used to be a setting for in under Tools > Options. So I'm still hoping it's there somewhere. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set here: Tools > Options > Text Editor > Advanced
[image]

Hope it can help you.